# Rails 4 select image for background data?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, src

I'm trying to make a page where the user can create a post.

Before he can create his post, I want him to select an image for that post.
he can choose between an image ore an empty(white) background for the post.
then he will be send to the new form.

I want to know how can I send data from a page to the new form?
Is this possible in rails or do I have to use javascript/jQuery?

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you're asking. Do you want to know how to upload an image through a form, or just submit a form in general? Please clarify

Comment: No need of javascript/jQuery. So you are taking images from users or already existed images using as post background...!!!

Comment: You can add data to Rails session that can be accessible to new form, but please detail your question with some code if you've.

Comment: So basically you want a [multi step form](https://www.google.nl/search?q=rails+multi+step+form)?

Comment: yes the user can create a post/card. so i want him to choose between an empty background ore an image as background. example: the user is on the index page and select and image. how can i send the data(src) of the clicked image. to the new form?

Comment: So, I propose that you start looking at _multi step form_ information/implementations and try to make use of them. If you have more specific problems, please post a new question with more details and the example code you created and is failing.

Comment: thank you for reply, yes i have the multi step form. but want to send the data to the new ore input form. i don't know how to handle that.